# Fill na values by adding x to previous row pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with a column named SAM with following data

```
SAM
3
5
9
Nan
Nan
24
40
Nan
57
```

Now I want to Insert `12`, `15` and `43` respectively in the `Nan` values (because `9+3=12`, `12+3=15`, and `40+3=43`). In other words, fill any `Nan` row by adding `3` to previous row (which can also be `Nan`).

I know this can be done by iterating through a for loop. But can we do it in a vectorized manner? Like some modified version of `ffill` (which could have been used here if we didn't have consecutive NaNs)  in `pandas.fillna()`.

Comment: In the future, please do not use `<br>` to format your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this vectorized approach:

```
nul = df['SAM'].isnull()
nul.groupby((nul.diff() == 1).cumsum()).cumsum()*3 + df['SAM'].ffill()

#0     3.0
#1     5.0
#2     9.0
#3    12.0
#4    15.0
#5    24.0
#6    40.0
#7    43.0
#8    57.0
#Name: SAM, dtype: float64
```

1. Divide the missing values in the series into chunks and add 3,6,9 etc to the missing value positions depending on the length of each chunk;
2. Add the forward filled values from `SAM` column to the result.