# how to find the count the difference back to the previous zero in a list?

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, dataframe, recursive-datastructures

I have below list

[7, 2, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 4]

and the result list is

[1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2]

the result obtained by  with the below logic

For each value, count the difference back to the previous zero (or the start of the Series,
whichever is closer).

am trying to implement , but not able to get .

So how to find the previous zero position , such that we can get that series ?

I tried below , but somehow it is failing , and it is seems not good solution

```
import pandas as pd



df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [7, 2, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 4]})

#print(df)

df_series = df['X']

print(df_series.iloc[-1])

target_series = pd.Series([])

#print(target_series)

def calculate_value(i,actual_index): 
    if(df_series.iloc[i-1] == 0):
        if(i < 0):
            zero_position = i + df_series.size-1
            if(actual_index - 0 < zero_position):
                target_series[actual_index]=actual_index+1
                return
            else:
                target_series[actual_index]=zero_position
                return
        else:
            target_series[actual_index]=target_series[actual_index]+1
            return
    else:
        if(i+df_series.size != actual_index):   
            calculate_value(i-1,actual_index)


for i in df.index:
    if(df_series[i]==0 and i!=0):
        target_series[i]=0
    elif(df_series[i]!=0 and i==0):
        target_series[i]=1
    else:
        calculate_value(i,i)


print(target_series)
```

Comment: why the pandas/ dataframe tags?

Answer (score 4):

If you want a Pandas one-liner solution:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([7, 2, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 4])

(s.groupby(s.eq(0).cumsum().mask(s.eq(0))).cumcount() + 1).mask(s.eq(0), 0).tolist()
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you stick to the list you can get your result quite easily:

```
l = [7, 2, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 4]
i = 0
r = []

for element in l:
    if element != 0:
        i += 1
    else:
        i = 0
    r.append(i)
r
#[1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working solution for you:

```
a = [7, 2, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 4]

b = []
z_pos = -1
for i, n in enumerate(a):
    if n == 0:
        z_pos = i
    b.append(i - z_pos)
print(b)  # [1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2]
```

It does not use anything too fancy so I explaining its internal workings is unnecessary I think. If however there is something that is not clear to you let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use python only, here is the solution:

```
a = [7, 2, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 4]
z = None
b = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] != 0 and z== None:
        b.append(i+1)
    elif a[i] == 0:
        b.append(0)
        z = 0
    else:
        z += 1
        b.append(z)
```

`b` is the required list.

Comment: "the" solution? Seriously?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it with a standard list, not Pandas dataframe, but the logic is the same

```
arr = [7,2,0,3,4,5,1,0,2]
arr2 = []
counter = 1
for item in arr:
    if(item==0):
      counter = 0

    arr2.append(counter)
    counter+=1

print(arr2)
```

You can see the code working [here](https://repl.it/@lughaidhdev/ActiveUnrulySquab).

Some explanations:

What you want is a sort of `counter` between two `0` in your array.
So you loop over your array, and each time you encounter a `0` you reset your counter, and you insert the value of your counter each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a fan of shortness instead of readability or effectiveness, you can also roll with this:

```
a = [7, 2, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 4]
distances = [([0]+a)[:idx][::-1].index(0) for idx in range(1, len(a)+2)][1:]
```

Which gives the desired result:

```
print(distances)
>> [1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Simpler/shorter way to do that: `[(a[i::-1]+[0]).index(0) for i in range(len(a))]`

Comment: Yup, simpler and better.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with no for loops or apply, just some pandas `groupby` fun.

We use

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [7, 2, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 4]})

# make a new column with zeros at zeros and nans elsewhere
df = df.assign(idx_from_0=df.loc[df.X==0])

nul = df['idx_from_0'].isnull()
df.assign(idx_from_0=nul.groupby((nul.diff() == 1).cumsum()).cumsum())

Out[1]:
    X   idx_from_0
0   7   1.0
1   2   2.0
2   0   0.0
3   3   1.0
4   4   2.0
5   2   3.0
6   5   4.0
7   0   0.0
8   3   1.0
9   4   2.0
```

The `cumsum` forward fill add one was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41146058/4049396).