# pandas forward fill Time Stamp columns with specific value (1 second)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas.Series like:

```
Timestamp_data:
0   2018-09-26 04:38:32.544 
1   NaT
2   NaT
3   NaT
4   2018-09-26 04:58:32.544
5   NaT
```

And I would like to add consecutively 1 second to each NaT from the previous available:

```
    Timestamp_data:
0   2018-09-26 04:38:32.544 
1   2018-09-26 04:39:32.544
2   2018-09-26 04:40:32.544
3   2018-09-26 04:41:32.544
4   2018-09-26 04:58:32.544
5   2018-09-26 04:59:32.544
```

The was a post like this:

> [Fill na values by adding x to previous row pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41145898/fill-na-values-by-adding-x-to-previous-row-pandas)

But in the present numpy version the np.diff() has a TypeError for Booleans.

Comment: How working my solution? Do you want add one minute or one second?

Comment: Perfect, thank you ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create timedeltas only for consecutive missing datetimes with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html), because filter only this rows is added [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) for filling `0 timedelta` for existing data.

Last forward filling `NaT` and add new `Series`:

```
print (df)
           Timestamp_data
0 2018-09-26 04:25:32.544
1 2018-09-26 04:38:32.544
2                     NaT
3                     NaT
4                     NaT
5 2018-09-26 04:58:32.544
6                     NaT

m = df['Timestamp_data'].notna()
#old pandas alternative
#m = df['Timestamp_data'].notnull()

s = (pd.to_timedelta(df[~m].groupby(m.cumsum()).cumcount() + 1, unit='s')
       .reindex(df.index, fill_value=0))
```

Last is multiple one second by `60` for add `1` minute:

```
df['Timestamp_data'] = df['Timestamp_data'].ffill()  + s * 60

print (df)
           Timestamp_data
0 2018-09-26 04:25:32.544
1 2018-09-26 04:38:32.544
2 2018-09-26 04:39:32.544
3 2018-09-26 04:40:32.544
4 2018-09-26 04:41:32.544
5 2018-09-26 04:58:32.544
6 2018-09-26 04:59:32.544
```

For one second only remove multiple by `60`:

```
df['Timestamp_data'] = df['Timestamp_data'].ffill()  + s 
print (df)
           Timestamp_data
0 2018-09-26 04:25:32.544
1 2018-09-26 04:38:32.544
2 2018-09-26 04:38:33.544
3 2018-09-26 04:38:34.544
4 2018-09-26 04:38:35.544
5 2018-09-26 04:58:32.544
6 2018-09-26 04:58:33.544
```