# pyspark forward fill Time Stamp columns with specific value (1 second)

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

in the past I've asked this question regarding python pandas library: [pandas forward fill Time Stamp columns with specific value (1 second)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54441535/pandas-forward-fill-time-stamp-columns-with-specific-value-1-second)

But now I will be doing huge data processing in pyspark so would ask for another solution in pyspark:

I have a spark DataFrame:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(a=1, b='2018-09-26 04:38:32.544', c='11', d='foo'),
                            Row(a=2, b='', c='22', d='bar'),
                            Row(a=3, b='', c='33', d='foo'),
                            Row(a=4, b='', c='44', d='bar'),
                            Row(a=5, b='2018-09-26 04:58:32.544', c='55', d='foo'),
                            Row(a=6, b='', c='66', d='bar')])
df.show(truncate=False)

|a  |b                      |c  |d  |
+---+-----------------------+---+---+
|1  |2018-09-26 04:38:32.544|11 |foo|
|2  |                       |22 |bar|
|3  |                       |33 |foo|
|4  |                       |44 |bar|
|5  |2018-09-26 04:58:32.544|55 |foo|
|6  |                       |66 |bar|
+---+-----------------------+---+---+
```

And I would like to add consecutively 1 second to each NaT from the previous available:

```
|a  |b                      |c  |d  |
+---+-----------------------+---+---+
|1  |2018-09-26 04:38:32.544|11 |foo|
|2  |2018-09-26 04:39:32.544|22 |bar|
|3  |2018-09-26 04:40:32.544|33 |foo|
|4  |2018-09-26 04:41:32.544|44 |bar|
|5  |2018-09-26 04:58:32.544|55 |foo|
|6  |2018-09-26 04:59:32.544|66 |bar|
+---+-----------------------+---+---+
```

I've read that **udf's** should be avoided as they will slow down the processing on millions of rows. Thanks for help!

**UPDATE 2019/09/09**

After talking with `@cronoik` below there is a case study where one column `d` is for partitioning the dataset:

```
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([Row(a=1, b='2018-09-26 04:38:32.544', c='11', d='foo'),
                             Row(a=2, b='', c='22', d='foo'),
                             Row(a=3, b='', c='33', d='foo'),
                             Row(a=4, b='', c='44', d='foo'),
                             Row(a=5, b='2018-09-26 04:58:32.544', c='55', d='foo'),
                             Row(a=6, b='', c='66', d='foo'),
                             Row(a=1, b='2018-09-28 05:40:32.544', c='111', d='bar'),
                             Row(a=2, b='', c='222', d='bar'),
                             Row(a=3, b='2018-09-28 05:49:32.544', c='333', d='bar'),
                             Row(a=4, b='', c='444', d='bar'),
                             Row(a=5, b='2018-09-28 05:55:32.544', c='555', d='bar'),
                             Row(a=6, b='', c='666', d='bar')]

|a  |b                      |c  |d  |
+---+-----------------------+---+---+
|1  |2018-09-26 04:38:32.544|11 |foo|
|2  |                       |22 |foo|
|3  |                       |33 |foo|
|4  |                       |44 |foo|
|5  |2018-09-26 04:58:32.544|55 |foo|
|6  |                       |66 |foo|
|1  |2018-09-28 05:40:32.544|111|bar|
|2  |                       |222|bar|
|3  |2018-09-28 05:49:32.544|333|bar|
|4  |                       |444|bar|
|5  |2018-09-28 05:55:32.544|555|bar|
|6  |                       |666|bar|
+---+-----------------------+---+---+
```

Comment: Is `a` something like a unique key? Does the row with a==1 always has a value for b?

Comment: @cronoik -> you can imagine it as an index so yes, it is a unique value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not the most efficient solution as we can't partition the dataframe according to your requirements. That means that all the data is loaded to a single partition and ordered there. Maybe someone can come up with a better solution.

The code below use a [lag](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lag) window function which returns the value of the previous row. We apply this only when the current value for `b` is null otherwise we keep the current value. When the current value is null, we add one second to the value of the previous row. We have to do this several times as a row which contains null in the `b` column and the previous row which also contains null in the 'b' column will get null returned from lag (i.e. lag is not applied consecutively and therefore we have to do this by ourself).

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(a=1, b='2018-09-26 04:38:32.544', c='11', d='foo'),
                            Row(a=2, b='', c='22', d='bar'),
                            Row(a=3, b='', c='33', d='foo'),
                            Row(a=4, b='', c='44', d='bar'),
                            Row(a=5, b='2018-09-26 04:58:32.544', c='55', d='foo'),
                            Row(a=6, b='', c='66', d='bar')])

df = df.withColumn('a',  df.a.cast("int"))
df = df.withColumn('b',  df.b.cast("timestamp"))

w = Window.orderBy('a')

while df.filter(df.b.isNull()).count() != 0:
    df = df.withColumn('b', F.when(df.b.isNotNull(), df.b).otherwise(F.lag('b').over(w)  + F.expr('INTERVAL 1 SECONDS')))

df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+---+-----------------------+---+---+ 
| a |                     b | c | d | 
+---+-----------------------+---+---+ 
| 1 |2018-09-26 04:38:32.544|11 |foo| 
| 2 |2018-09-26 04:38:33.544|22 |bar| 
| 3 |2018-09-26 04:38:34.544|33 |foo| 
| 4 |2018-09-26 04:38:35.544|44 |bar| 
| 5 |2018-09-26 04:58:32.544|55 |foo| 
| 6 |2018-09-26 04:58:33.544|66 |bar| 
+---+-----------------------+---+---+
```

**UPDATE 2019/09/09**
In your edit you said that the column `d` can be used as partition key. There is not much you have to change for partitioning. Just replace `w = Window.orderBy('a')` with `w = Window.partitionBy('d').orderBy('a')` and spark will generate a partition for each distinct value of d and execute the code in parallel for each partition.

Comment: Hi, getting back to the topic, what did you mean with the phrase: _"as we can't partition the dataframe according to your requirements"_ . What could be done to improve it?

Comment: Partitioning would allow us to speed up the execution of the above code significantly (probably) but that requires a feature (column) which allows us to partition (i.e. separate) the data. For example that `foo` and `bar` in column `d` are two different things which needed to be handled separately. This allows us to execute the code in parallel for each partition. But this is only possible if your use case allows it.

Comment: So I've updated the question, could you post the 2nd solution? Is there an option to avoid `while ...` line as I would like to place the code on longer script with many `.withColumn(...) \ .withColumn(...) ` transformations ?

Comment: I have updated my answer regarding the partitioning. Regarding the while loop: Currently I can't think of a way to avoid that loop. There is probably one, but it currently doesn't crosses my mind.

Comment: Thanks a lot! If you think of something about the while clause, of course share your thoughts ! :)